# How to stop spinner with error message if there is a server error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have angular 8 application.

And I want to show error message when there is a api call error.

So I have a component where a generic error will be loaded. And in a other component you can then call that method.
But the error message will not been shown and also the spinner doesnt go away if there is a api call error. So the spinner will been shown infinite

So this is the generic component:

```
export class IsLoadingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() message: string;
  @Input() showSpinner = true;
  showError = false;

  public text: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.text = this.message + '...';
  }

  displayLoadErrorMessage( msg: string ) {
    this.text = msg;
    this.showSpinner = false;
    this.showError = true;
  }
}
```

and this is the component where I call the error message:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 error = null;
isLoading: IsLoadingComponent;

 this.user$.pipe(switchMap(({ profile }) => this.indicatorService.get('profile.participant'))).subscribe(
      (i: any) => {
        this.setFavIndicators(i);
      },
     error => {

      this.error = true;


        setTimeout(() => {
           this.handleSubmitError('Indicatoren kunnen niet worden geladen!!');
        }, 500);
      }

    );
}

  handleSubmitError(msg: string) {
    this.isLoading.displayLoadErrorMessage(msg);
  }
```

And this is template of Dashboard:

```
 <app-is-loading *ngIf="!favIndicatorsLoaded && !error" message="Indicatoren worden geladen" class="darkgrey"></app-is-loading>

     <p *ngIf="error" >
      <app-is-loading   showSpinner = false class="darkgrey"  >
      </app-is-loading>
    </p>
```

But so the spinner is still going and the message is not shown.

So what I have to change?

Thnak you

Yes, but if I do this:

```
 setTimeout(() => {
           this.handleSubmitError('Indicatoren kunnen niet worden geladen!!');
        }, 500);
```

Then it will not shown the message.

But if I do this:

```
 <p *ngIf="error" >
      <app-is-loading   [showSpinner] = false message="Indicatoren kunnen niet worden geladen" class="darkgrey"  >
      </app-is-loading>
    </p>
```

Then it will shown the message. But now it is double. Because handleSubmitError expects a message.

That I still dont understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand what you want, to show spinner upon http request and once get caught an error it will in few milliseconds hides the spinner the display the message.

Tried to simulate what you want to accomplish.
And this is what I come up with using input binding.

dashboard templates:

```
<app-is-loading *ngIf="showSpinner && !msg" [showSpinner]="showSpinner"</app-is-loading>
<app-is-loading *ngIf="!showSpinner" [errorMessage]="msg"></app-is-loading>
```

dashboard ts:

```
// declared variable
showSpinner: boolean;
msg = '';

// inside http request, showSpinner set to true
this.showSpinner = true;

// inside http request error block/function
setTimeout(() => {
    this.showSpinner = false; // showSpinner set to false
    this.msg = 'Indicatoren kunnen niet worden geladen!!';
}, 500);
```

Generic component template

```
<p *ngIf="showSpinner">Spinner</p>
<p *ngIf="!showSpinner">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
```

Generic component ts file inside class

```
@Input() showSpinner: boolean;
@Input() errorMessage: string;
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you. Of course it is property binding. But I edit the post. What is your suggestion? Thank you

Comment: So the whole handleSubmitError is not necessarily anymore